# Flush Magento system

Tags: magento2, cache, websites, pagespeed

**Flush Magento Cache
Flush Cache Storage
Refresh Cache.**

Do Flushing process help website speedup?
I have noticed that whenever we are doing flushing cache and refresh cache after that page speed test is better.

Did anyone experience the same?

Comment: Cache flush never improve page speed.

Comment: Never experienced this, should have the opposite effect once cache warmed.

Comment: this depends on your system and cache storage